# Numbering certain divs inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that can be duplicated what i want is to add numbering in front of it so the result is similar to this

```css
.form_div div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_div">
 <div class="form_div">
  <div class="count">1</div>
  <div><input name="name_1" id="name_1" value="" type="text" /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form_div">
  <div class="count">2</div>
  <div class="form_div"><input name="name_2" id="name_2" value="" type="text" /></div>
 </div>
  <div class="form_div">
  <div class="count">3</div>
  <div><input name="name_3" id="name_3" value="" type="text" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I got this function that i call in the duplicate function but it will set the same number to every div with a class .count

```
function divcounter(){
var numbercounter = 1;
$('#main_div').find('.count').each(function(){
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".count").text(numbercounter ++);

});
}
```

What i want it to do is numbering the divs with that class that are not hidden 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: why not use its index just add 1 because index is base 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer the current element inside the **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method.

```
function divcounter(){
    var numbercounter = 1;
    $('#main_div').find('.count').each(function(){
        var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).text(numbercounter++);
        //^^^^-----------here--------
    });
}
```

```js
function divcounter() {
  var numbercounter = 1;
  $('#main_div').find('.count').each(function() {
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).text(numbercounter++);
    //^^^^-----------here--------
  });
}
divcounter();
```

```css
.form_div div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_1" id="name_1" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">2</div>
    <div class="form_div">
      <input name="name_2" id="name_2" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">3</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_3" id="name_3" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can even avoid the counter variable by using index param in callback funtion.

```
function divcounter(){
    $('#main_div').find('.count').each(function(i){
        //--------------------------------------^^^----
        var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).text(i + 1);
        //^^^^-------^^^^^^----here--------
    });
}
```

```js
function divcounter() {
  $('#main_div').find('.count').each(function(i) {
    //--------------------------------------^^^----
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).text(i + 1);
    //^^^^-------^^^^^^----here--------
  });
}
divcounter();
```

```css
.form_div div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_1" id="name_1" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">2</div>
    <div class="form_div">
      <input name="name_2" id="name_2" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">3</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_3" id="name_3" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Although use single selector instead of chained **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find)** if you don't want any reference to `$('#main_div')`.

```
$('#main_div .count')
```

Comment: I used the second function using index but this will also count the hidden divs as i said i need it to avoid the hidden divs.

Comment: @John change the selector to $('#main_div').find('.count:visible') or $('#main_div .count:visible')

Answer (score 0):

Find the `.count` element using `this` context or else `text` will be applied to all `.count` elements

```js
function divcounter() {
  var numbercounter = 1;
  $('#main_div').find('.count').each(function() {
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".count", this).text(numbercounter++);
    //--------^^^^^

  });
}
divcounter();
```

```css
.form_div div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_1" id="name_1" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">2</div>
    <div class="form_div">
      <input name="name_2" id="name_2" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">3</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_3" id="name_3" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `jQuery.find`

```js
function divcounter() {
  var numbercounter = 1;
  $('#main_div').find('.count').each(function() {
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).find(".count").text(numbercounter++);
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
}
divcounter();
```

```css
.form_div div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_1" id="name_1" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">2</div>
    <div class="form_div">
      <input name="name_2" id="name_2" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">3</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_3" id="name_3" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` already refers to `.count` ( check `$('#main_div').find('.count')` )

Comment: @PranavCBalan – That was quiet bad from me... Little over-engineering of things ;( I'm laughing since then... ;P

Answer (score 0):

```js
function divcounter() {
  $('.count').each(function(i,v) {
    $(this).text( i+1 );

  });
}
divcounter();
```

```css
.form_div div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_1" id="name_1" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">2</div>
    <div class="form_div">
      <input name="name_2" id="name_2" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_div">
    <div class="count">3</div>
    <div>
      <input name="name_3" id="name_3" value="" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use index then add 1 because it is base 0